# How can I stub method in rspec model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have a below method in my model and I want to stub the value of below

"`esxi_hosts = RezApi.new.get_esxi(type, vrealm_id)`"

with values like `[{x: "y"}]`

what is the way to do it in rspec.

```
def create_esxi
if (["vRealm", "Praxis Parent vRealm", "Praxis Child vRealm"].include?(self.collection_type.try(:name)))
  esxi_hosts = []
  if(( self.parent && self.parent.parent && self.parent.collection_type.name.upcase == "POD" && self.parent.parent.collection_type.name.upcase == "DATACENTER") or ( self.parent && self.parent.parent && self.parent.parent.parent && (self.parent.collection_type.name.upcase == "RELEASE - PRAXIS" or self.parent.collection_type.name.upcase == "RELEASE - SUBSCRIPTION") && self.parent.parent.collection_type.name.upcase == "POD" && self.parent.parent.parent.collection_type.name.upcase == "DATACENTER"))
    vrealm_type = collection_type.try(:name)
    vrealm_id = "d#{self.parent.parent.instance}p#{self.parent.instance}v#{instance}"
    case vrealm_type
      when   "vRealm"
        types = ["vrealm-multitenant-dr2c", "vpc-standard"]
        types.each do |type|
          if esxi_hosts.empty?
            esxi_hosts = RezApi.new.get_esxi(type, vrealm_id)
          end
        end
      when   "Praxis Parent vRealm"
        esxi_hosts = RezApi.new.get_esxi("praxis-core", vrealm_id)
      when   "Praxis Child vRealm"
        esxi_hosts = RezApi.new.get_esxi("praxis-node-mgmt", vrealm_id)
    end
  end
  if esxi_hosts.flatten.any?
    assign_esxi(esxi_hosts)
  end
 end
end
```

I have already tried the below code but it didnt work

```
      require 'spec_helper'

describe "Esxi Host creation from Rez Api" do
  let(:federation)  {create(:federation_collection, parent_id: nil, name: "Test", usage: "Tech Ops hosted in Vmware Data Centers", owner: "--", date_from: "2015-08-26", date_to: nil, collection_type_id: 2, zone_name: "se.vpc.vmw")}
  let(:datacenter) {create(:datacenter_collection, name: "Datacenter", parent_id: federation.id)}
  let(:pod)  {create(:pod_collection, parent_id: datacenter.id)}
  let(:fqdn) {"d2p1s0ch10srv0v101-esx0.se.vpc.vmw"}
  let(:vrealm1)  {create(:vrealm_collection, name: "vRealm1", parent_id: pod.id)}
  let(:vrealm2) {create(:vrealm_collection, name: "vRealm2", parent_id: pod.id)}


  context "When response has esxi hosts " do
    let(:rez_response) {[{"esx0"=>{"nodefqdn"=>"d2p1s0ch10srv0.se.vpc.vmw","fqdn"=>"d2p1s0ch10srv0v101-esx0.se.vpc.vmw","vmk0"=>{"pg_name"=>"d2p1v101-esx-pg-1062","ip_addr"=>"10.141.112.71","netmask"=>"255.255.255.0",},"vmk1"=>{"pg_name"=>"d2p1pod-sto-pg-17","ip_addr"=>"172.16.160.51","netmask"=>"255.255.252.0"},"vmk2"=>{"pg_name"=>"d2p1v101-ftx-pg-1063","ip_addr"=>"172.16.165.126","netmask"=>"255.255.255.0"}}}]}
    subject {RezApi.new}
    it "should create esxi hosts" do
      allow(subject).to receive(:get_esxi).with("type", "101").and_return(rez_response)
      expect(subject).to receive(:get_esxi).with("type", "101").and_return(rez_response)
      vrealm1.create_esxi
      vrealm1.resources.map(&:fqdn).should include(fqdn)
    end
  end

end
```

Getting the below error

```
     Failures:

  1) Esxi Host creation from Rez Api When response has esxi hosts  should create esxi hosts
     Failure/Error: expect(subject).to receive(:get_esxi).with("type", "101").and_return(rez_response)
       (#<RezApi:0xc26d69c>).get_esxi("type", "101")
           expected: 1 time with arguments: ("type", "101")
           received: 0 times
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with below code

```
RezApi.any_instance.stub(:get_esxi).with("vrealm-multitenant-dr2c", "101").and_return(success_response)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  subject { RezApi.new }

  context "....." do
    it "....." do
      allow(subject).to receive(:get_esxi).with("type", "101").and_return({x: "y"})
      expect(subject).to receive(:get_esxi).with("type", "101").and_return({x: "y"})
    end
  end
```

So, your updated test code should be this:

```
describe "Esxi Host creation from Rez Api" do

  let(:federation)  {create(:federation_collection, parent_id: nil, name: "Test", usage: "Tech Ops hosted in Vmware Data Centers", owner: "--", date_from: "2015-08-26", date_to: nil, collection_type_id: 2, zone_name: "se.vpc.vmw")}
  let(:datacenter) {create(:datacenter_collection, name: "Datacenter", parent_id: federation.id)}
  let(:pod)  {create(:pod_collection, parent_id: datacenter.id)}
  let(:fqdn) {"d2p1s0ch10srv0v101-esx0.se.vpc.vmw"}
  let(:vrealm1)  {create(:vrealm_collection, name: "vRealm1", parent_id: pod.id)}
  let(:vrealm2) {create(:vrealm_collection, name: "vRealm2", parent_id: pod.id)}

  context "When response has esxi hosts " do
    let(:rez_response) {[{"esx0"=>{"nodefqdn"=>"d2p1s0ch10srv0.se.vpc.vmw","fqdn"=>"d2p1s0ch10srv0v101-esx0.se.vpc.vmw","vmk0"=>{"pg_name"=>"d2p1v101-esx-pg-1062","ip_addr"=>"10.141.112.71","netmask"=>"255.255.255.0",},"vmk1"=>{"pg_name"=>"d2p1pod-sto-pg-17","ip_addr"=>"172.16.160.51","netmask"=>"255.255.252.0"},"vmk2"=>{"pg_name"=>"d2p1v101-ftx-pg-1063","ip_addr"=>"172.16.165.126","netmask"=>"255.255.255.0"}}}}

    subject { RezApi.new }

    it "should create esxi hosts" do
      allow(subject).to receive(:get_esxi).with("vrealm-multitenant-dr2c", "101").and_return(rez_response)
      expect(subject).to receive(:get_esxi).with("vrealm-multitenant-dr2c", "101").and_return(rez_response)
      vrealm1.create_esxi
      vrealm1.resources.map(&:fqdn).should include(fqdn)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: its not working, geeting the  error ----->


 Failure/Error: expect(RezApi.new).to receive(:get_esxi).with("vrealm-multitenant-dr2c", "101").and_return(rez_response)
       (#<RezApi:0xac913a0>).get_esxi("vrealm-multitenant-dr2c", "101")
           expected: 1 time with arguments: ("vrealm-multitenant-dr2c", "101")
           received: 0 times

Comment: Please paste your spec test code and the stack trace of the erro you got.

Comment: @loganathan let me know if the updated code works for you or not.

Comment: `subject {RezApi.new}` should be inside the context. Could you just copy my answer and paste it in your test code and try? It should work

Comment: Yes I did but getting teh same error, updated the details